# In which context the linux block device driver request runs?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, scheduling

> Finally, the invocation of the request function is (usually) entirely
>   asynchronous with respect to the actions of any user-space process.
>   You cannot assume that the kernel is running in the context of the
>   process that initiated the current request

lines from [LDD3](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch16.pdf)

My doubt is whether block driver process request in kernel context? If yes is it executed using kernel thread (kworker) or any other thread?

Comment: Google bioset (as in block i/o). Try the AskUbuntu link, ignore the paranoia in the first three replies, and find the graphic block. Consensus is that Kernel hands off a lot of the work to helper processes all owned by process 2 (kthreadd) so they can be scheduled, watchdogged, and play nicely with the neighbours.

Comment: Note that kthreads run in kernel context, but are handled more or less like user threads.